# 'int' object has no attribute 'append' while appending with indexes

Tags: python

```
errors = [[[]]]
x = 0
y = 0
fun = 0
zen = 0


def solve():
    cntBe = set()
    global fun
    global zen
    global errors
    global x
    global y
    global arr
    for i in range(0, 8):
        if arr[x][i] != 0 or arr[i][y] != 0:
            cntBe.add(arr[x][i])
            cntBe.add(arr[i][y])
    cntBe.discard(0)
    errors.append(x)
    errors[zen].append(y) #error here
    #errors[zen][fun].append(list(cntBe)) #error here
    fun += 1
    zen += 1
```

plz don't jusge my variable names, its a work in progress. However, it tells me the error of the title whenever i try to append stuff with the indexes in the array, I have used this many times in the program and it worked, but for some reason, it does not work here. I am trying to append these values in an array. so, the x axis goes in one dimension, the y axis goes in another, and the set of numbers goes in another dimension. It is for a soduku program, in order to keep track of a boxes position and the numbers it cannot be. The for loop tests the rows and columns to see what the numbers cannot be. Then I subtract 0 because that just means it is an empty space. arr is a list of all the nubers in the soduku grid, and errors is the array i am trying to make as explained above. it is currently, just an empty list 3d list, and the x and y variables correspond with square positions. fun and zen are just numbers to hold index values and they both start at 0

Comment: Posting your code without telling us what you are actually trying to do is not going to help. What problem are you trying to solve, and can you provide example input and expected output?

Comment: Please include the what each variable is before you run your code, and the full error traceback so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: `errors` isn't defined. Is this code from inside a function? Also can you post the traceback with the offending line and error in the question body. In the end its clear that `errors` is an `int`. If that's unexpected, its a question of where you set `errors` not where you use it.

Comment: I added more details, sorry about the obscurity, I have never asked a question on stack overflow before, if you have more question, please ask

Comment: Kindly show us where `errors` is defined

Comment: i showed the diefinitions for the global variables

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is because `errors` is a one dimensional list or array. If it were a 2d list you would not get that error.
This :

```
zen = 0
errors = [[]]
error [zen].append ('anything')
```

will not give that error.
This :

```
zen = 0
errors = []
error [zen].append ('anything')
```

will!